# IME issue in Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox in my wpf application. I gave maxLength to 10 via code in textchanged event. If i enter English character its working perfect. But if i change the language to Hiragana(Japanese) through IME the below issue happened.

While I enter the 11th character, the textbox automatically appending the first 10 character to itself that means 21 characters (10 + 10 + last entered character).

While debugging, textchanged event executing many times.

Thanks in advance.

Ram

Comment: can you show us your code / what you have done so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the text in a textchanged event will recursively call the textchanged event again. 
That is the looping you are seeing in your debugging.

The solution is to remove textchange handling when you update the value then re-add it after.

```
    private void MyTextbox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Act on the 11th character
        if (MyTextbox.Text.Length != 11)
            return;

        // Remove handling of text changed event so we can update without recursive calls
        MyTextbox.TextChanged -= MyTextbox_OnTextChanged;

        // Update textbox value - example based on your question
        var valueWithoutNewCharacter = MyTextbox.Text.Substring(0, 10 - 1); // strings are 0 based
        MyTextbox.Text = valueWithoutNewCharacter + valueWithoutNewCharacter + MyTextbox.Text.Substring(10, 1);

        // Re-add the handling of the text changed event
        MyTextbox.TextChanged += MyTextbox_OnTextChanged;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply...

Actually my textbox having total 3 lines. Each line's maxlength is 10.

Comment: I tested this code. Actually i want only 10 character in a line. In your code, you are making the issue what i am getting
MyTextbox.Text = valueWithoutNewCharacter + valueWithoutNewCharacter + MyTextbox.Text.Substring(10, 1);.